# How to define tables dynamically in DataContext for Windows Phone 7 development?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7, datacontext, dynamically-generated

I am trying to develop application for Windows Phone 7 and I want to store data locally, but the definition & data will be downloaded from the server. So, table names & columns are not defined yet until the application is running.

I read from MSDN below that there are three different types of storing data locally.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541(VS.92).aspx

There is also an example on how to create data context by extending DataTable class and using Table attribute on the table class.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202876(v=VS.92).aspx#BKMK_BuildingtheDataContext

But, there is no example nor tutorial on how to achieve the dynamic table definition. So, I can do below code (just an example).

```
var table = myDataContext.AddTable("A"); 
table.AddColumn("Field1", AFlag.PrimaryKey, typeof(int));
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The DataTable class is not included in the .NET version for WP7. Do you mean DataGrid? Are your trying to dynamically create your UI? Or the data?

Comment: I intended to do both data and UI (with simple output). There is an example of defining the table by creating class definition, but that's a static one and resides at the Windows Phone 7 device. 

[Table]
public class ToDoItem : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging


I need to be able to define table in run-time and follow what the most likely events (NotifyPropertyChanging("ItemName")) and data (private string _itemName) similar to the one in example.

Answer (score 0):

As ColinE mentions in his comment, the `DataSet` / `DataTable` family of classes are not available in WP7. You'll need to define your object model if that is the best way to describe your business logic.

Comment: I don't know if even there is DataSet/DataTable, then I can use it with whatever the Windows Phone 7 framework has to store local data. But, I am looking for any possibilities.

Comment: WP7 has a LINQ-to-SQL implementation that has a SqlCE backing. See [Local Database Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860(v=VS.92).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> So, table names & columns are not defined yet until the application is running.

This doesn't make much sense. If you don't know the data structure, how did you ever intent to persist them between runs of the application?

You probably meant it's not defined until the **first run** of the application?

Comment: The application may receive newer definition (with cache time). But, that doesn't matter.

Comment: Everything matters. You should look into the Sterling DB.